# mysql dump from linux to windows

Tags: mysql, database, linux, windows, mysql-workbench

Good day stack overflow.

I am having problems on importing an sql file to my windows machine. The sql file is from a linux machine. What happens is that the table names from linux are camel cased and when migrated to windows, all becomes lower cased. I don't want to adjust my codes to be able to access my database so is there anyway that I could achieve the camel-cased table names in windows?

Many thanks.

---

From linux table names:
 -> FooBar

When it is imported to mysql workbench in windows:
 -> foobar

the query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM FooBar; // when the program is pointed to the database in windows, it will spit out that the table does not exist because the table name is "foobar"
```

Comment: MySQL isn't case-sensitive, you _shouldn't need_ to adjust your scripts to make it work.

Comment: but my java codes are spitting out errors saying that the table does not exist. when i tried to edit the table name in my source code for retrieving data, it worked. its too exhausting to change all the table names, especially if the codes will be running on linux you'll have to revert again.

Comment: Good day, Oneb, I think there is another error at hand. Can you give us more info about the exact error you're receiving and the code that's triggering it?

Comment: To clarify, when you write your java code, it works perfectly with all lower case but not camel case? Can you post exactly both the examples?

Comment: please see my edit folks.. well i guess this error is happening because I am using native jdbc, when I used hibernate it turned out to be working fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between Linux and Windows on how both operating systems store the table names (allowing lower case only or not).  This can be controlled by the `lower_case_table_names` system variable.  Your Windows installation, probably has this value set to 1 and your Linux server had this value set as 0.  Following the "[Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)" part of the User Manual, you have two options:

> Use `lower_case_table_names=1` on all systems. The main disadvantage
>   with this is that when you use `SHOW TABLES` or `SHOW DATABASES`, you do
>   not see the names in their original lettercase.

or

> Use `lower_case_table_names=0` on Unix and `lower_case_table_names=2` on
>   Windows. This preserves the lettercase of database and table names.
>   The disadvantage of this is that you must ensure that your statements
>   always refer to your database and table names with the correct
>   lettercase on Windows. If you transfer your statements to Unix, where
>   lettercase is significant, they do not work if the lettercase is
>   incorrect.

Some links:

- [`lower_case_table_names` System Variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names)
- [Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: Seems there is also a problem when escaping '.
Windows escapes as \', but Linux seems to require ''.