# Is named index case sensitive in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "table2" which has a index called "MYINDEX"
My question is when I use this index for join like:

```
select a from table1 left join table2 use index (MYINDEX)
```

Is it equivalent to the following query?

```
select a from table1 left join table2 use index (myindex)
```

Comment: In SQL, uppercase and lower case are equivalent. In Mysql, they might not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, database and table names may be case-sensitive, depending on the server OS and mysqld options. Column, index, stored routine, and event names are always case-insensitive. See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: actually I read that doc before but things are not clear to me. Does it mean named index name is case-insensitive or does it mean when you define an index the column names you use to define the index is case-incensitive..

Comment: Column names are **always** case-insensitive. That includes when defining indexes.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. But it's the same. All uses of an index name are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Following one of [my earlier posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225379/mysql-dump-from-linux-to-windows/13245362#13245362), there is a difference between Linux and Windows on how both operating systems store the table names (allowing lower case only or not). This can be controlled by the `lower_case_table_names` system variable. Your Windows installation, probably has this value set to 1 and your Linux server had this value set as 0. Following the ["Identifier Case Sensitivity"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) part of the User Manual, you have two options:

> Use `lower_case_table_names=1` on all systems. The main disadvantage
>   with this is that when you use `SHOW TABLES` or `SHOW DATABASES`, you do
>   not see the names in their original lettercase.

or

> Use `lower_case_table_names=0` on Unix and `lower_case_table_names=2` on
>   Windows. This preserves the lettercase of database and table names.
>   The disadvantage of this is that you must ensure that your statements
>   always refer to your database and table names with the correct
>   lettercase on Windows. If you transfer your statements to Unix, where
>   lettercase is significant, they do not work if the lettercase is
>   incorrect.

As for the index names, I would approach it in the same matter as for the database name, table names and/or column names.  To be on the safe side, assume that in the future you might have this problem.

Some links:

- [lower_case_table_names System Variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names)
- [Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)